# trap in bash function does not trigger

Tags: bash

I have a fairly complicated bash script hierarchy that depends on functions for nearly everything.  The main script is merely a shell that sources in appropriate functions (common ones like my output functions, etc. as well as specific ones for the task being executed) contained within their own files.

Within that framework, I have a particular function that needs to handle being interrupted and cleanup properly.  I am handling it's error cleanup in a subfunction within that function
i.e.

```
function my_function {
    function f_err_cleanup {
        do error cleanup tasks here
    } #/f_err_cleanup{}
    echo do stuff
    my_other_function -t "some var here"
    my_other_other_function var1 var2 var3
    echo do more stuff
} #/my_function{}
```

Adding a trap to the main script like this:

```
trap "declare -p FUNCNAME ; f_err_cleanup" INT QUIT TERM
```

fails due to it not knowing about the f_err_cleanup{} function - but the trap triggers.

> ```
> ^C./my_script.sh: line 1: declare: FUNCNAME: not found
> ./my_script.sh: line 1: f_err_cleanup: command not found
> [ ERROR 13 ]  Script "my_script.sh" failed.
> ```

Putting a trap inside my_function{} never triggers and cntl-c just drops out of the function with a 130 exit code (which the main script then handles generically.

```
trap "echo inside trap ; declare -p FUNCNAME" EXIT SIGHUP SIGQUIT SIGINT SIGTERM
```

The above snippet fails as follows when executed

```
^C[ ERROR 13 ]  Script "my_script.sh" failed.
```

Here's a snip from the outer script:

```
. my_function
my_function "$@" 2>&1 | tee -a "${RUNTIME_LOG}"
declare -i RC=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then
    f_err -f -c ${RC} -m "script \"${ME}\"failed\n"
else
    f_out "success\n"
    exit ${RC}
fi
```

f_err is a function to print an error message and exit with the provided code. *How can I get the trap to work from within the function?*

P.S. having the outer trap do a `declare -p FUNCNAME` returns that FUNCNAME is **unknown** as well, even though, as I understand it, it should show `FUNCNAME[0]="main"`

Comment: As an update, I have made a bit of progress since posting.
Removing the ` | tee -a "${RUNTIME_LOG}"` code segment from the function invocation allows the trap to be picked up from within the function as expected.
Unfortunately, we need that output to be captured for auditing purposes, so I have to either keep that `tee` or replace it with something similar.

Comment: Another note:  adding `set -o pipefail` gets the trap in my_script.sh to trigger, but that still does not facilitate the function-specific cleanup that needs to occur along with the auditing log.

Comment: The (extensive) set of pitfalls and caveats associated with `set -e` [is well-documented](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and they apply just as much to ERR traps. http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling is also pertinent, and written from a closer-to-neutral perspective. Note in particular the `errtrace` flag (needed for ERR traps or `set -e` to be inherited by functions).

Comment: ...in short, bash *does not have* a reliable error-management mechanism; it behooves someone writing code in bash to implement and carefully audit their code's error handling just as much as it behooves someone writing code in C or Go to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Putting a trap inside my_function{} never triggers

Yes it does. You just can't tell because you used `echo` to write to stdout, and stdout is a broken pipe because `tee` was killed by the sigint you're trying to handle.

Here's a MCVE:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunction() (
        trap 'mycleanup' INT
        mycleanup() {
                # Write to stderr so we can see it
                echo "Cleaning up" >&2
        }
        echo "doing stuff"
        sleep 42
        echo "done with stuff"
)

myfunction | tee file
```

(The function's explicit subshell is not strictly necessary, but helps prevent accidentally botching the script's own traps)

Here's what happens when you run and interrupt it:

```
$ ./myscript
doing stuff
^CCleaning up
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer because, while I have not resolved the conundrum of getting a trap to work when defined within a pipe, I have resolved my issue.
Because my pipe in this case is only to invoke `tee` to enable logging, I was able to change the piped line to
`my_function "$@" &> >( tee -a "${RUNTIME_LOG}" )`

Since there is no pipe involved anymore, the trap within the function will now trigger, leaving aside the questionable nature of bash error handling.